# Possibility to use d3.js with Java application

Tags: java, d3.js

Is this possible to **use d3.js (Data Driven Document) with Java** application.

Like, wants to write data from d3.js to Java. Again read data from java to d3.js.

If any sample application code is exist for (d3.js with Java) this, please share that link or code too.

**Note** : My screen would be containing more Graph, line chart and analytical data.

I found the following link, if possible, if there is any other Java with d3.js video tutorial available, please share the link.

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3