# Javascript Libraries / HTML output from Java Server Code

Tags: javascript, java, html

My question is broad but my need is specific.

I have data generated from an analytics server, 
**1 -** I use Java/Maven to extract the data via an SDK, and I would like to 
**2 -** Display the results in a web GUI, using some handy javascript visualisation libraries (D3 or else)

I know how to do 1 and 2 separately, and I was looking for some proven setups to do this in a clean chained way (No, I will NOT generate plain js code in java :) )

***Edit ***
I was considering passing all the parameters as session variables from java on the server side, to be retrieved in the JS code on the client side. This comes across to be a bit cumbersome, but may be the only way. just checking...

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: This is my question, sorry, I insist. I do not want it to be too specific, I need insight and advice. we are programmers/engineers with brains, not robots with only syntax question or specific error codes to solve.

Comment: I can post some more code if needed

Comment: Also, this question was (poorly) asked in a more specific manner but still has no answers, sooooo.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631681/possibility-to-use-d3-js-with-java-application

Comment: Instead of generating js code on server side..only pass the data as json to the client and render graphs and other elements to show data on client.

Comment: @atulquest93 thanks, that was what I figured out after some research 